# Float object is not iterable

Tags: python

```
list = "\n==== Names and Distances ====\n"
firstName = input ("Enter next person's first name >")
while firstName > "":
    distance= float(input("Enter distance thrown: "))
    lastName = input ("What is "+firstName+"'s last name?")
    list = list + firstName[0] + "." + lastName + str(distance) + "\n"
    firstName = input ("Enter next person's first name >")
    high=float(max(distance))
    low=float(min(distance))
print (list)
print ("The furthest distance is: " + high)
print ("The shorest distance is: " + low)
```

I got the Error 'float' object is not iterable.  I was curious what I was doing wrong and if I am completely off in writing this code.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `max(distance)` to do? You're providing it with a single number... what do you think is it going to tell you about that number? Same for `min(distance)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call `max()` and `min()` on a single value. Store the values in a list first, then call them on that instead.